# Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.spring framework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler]

Tags: spring, jersey, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to configure Jersey and Spring.  The error I'm getting is the following:

Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationCo
ntext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.spring
framework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema
/data/jpa]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/
springframework/aop/framework/AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor

because of the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

My pom also has the following spring dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

spring.verion = 3.2.0.RELEASE

spring-data.version = 1.2.1.RELEASE

If I remove the jersey-spring artifact then my unit tests for the repository fields passes without any exceptions.  However, when I start up my server jetty complains that it can't find:

"2013-05-03 00:10:43.885:WARN:oejs.Holder:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)"

Is the jersey-spring dependency compatible with my version of spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jersey has an older version of Spring AOP so I excluded the dependency and the issues were resolved.